# unable to set font and font size while export PDF using c#

Tags: c#, itext

I am unable to set font and font size while export data into PDF using c#.net

I've tried many different ways of doing this, each time failed. please help.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
htw.WriteBeginTag("p");
htw.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
htw.Write("Summary Details");
htw.WriteEndTag("p");
htw.WriteBreak();

htw.WriteBeginTag("p");
htw.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
htw.Write("Scrip Details");
htw.WriteEndTag("p");

gridCapitalGD.RenderControl(htw);

htw.WriteBreak();
htw.WriteBeginTag("p");
htw.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
htw.Write("Transaction Details");
htw.WriteEndTag("p");
grdViewTranDetail.RenderControl(htw);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Please do not use `HTMLWorker`. It is deprecated, unsupported, incomplete. Use iText 7 + pdfHTML instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `HTMLWorker`. It's deprecated, and was superseded by `XMLWorker`. Which is now also on its way to being deprecated, and is superseded by `pdfHTML`.

`HTMLWorker` was ever only intended to convert small snippets into pdf syntax. And the issues most people run into are not 'bugs' but simply scope limitations.

small example of `pdfHTML` and `iText7`:

```
// IO
File htmlSource = new File("input.html");
File pdfDest = new File("output.pdf");

// pdfHTML specific code
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), new FileOutputStream(pdfDest), converterProperties);
```

You can use CSS to set the font and font size, alternatively, you can play around with the ConverterProperties.

For information on pdfHTML, check out 
https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML